# How to find set of all automorphism of G in given question without evaluating each bijective map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

> Let $G$ be a group of order $4$, $G$ $=$ {$e$,$a$,$b$,$ab$}, $a^2 = b^2 = e , ab = ba$. Determine $A(G)$.Where $A(G)$ is set of all automorphisms of $G$.

What i did was - Since we know that for Homomorphism $e$ should map to $e$ in this case .Hence we are left with $3!$ $=$ $6$ permutations to be evaluated and then for each of them i checked homomorphic condition i.e $Ф(xy) =  Ф(x)Ф(y)$ .

I found that all of the six permutations are isomorphism and hence they belong to $A(G)$.

Is there any better method for finding $A(G)$ without evaluating and testing all the cases ( i mean just by little observation can we solve this problem ) ?

Comment: This is a special case of elementary $p$-groups. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_abelian_group#Automorphism_group

Answer (score 0):

You have Calculated there are 6 element in Aut(G).
Now there are only 2 possibilities Eithere $Aut(G)\cong S_3$ or $Aut(G)\cong Z_6$
Now , 

In case It is isomorphism to $Z_6$ then there are only one element of order 2 .but

Here 

1) $a\to b,b\to a$ all other elements are maps to same
2) $a\to ab,ab\to a$ all other elements are maps to same
Similarly you can contruct one more element which have order2.
SO 
$Aut(G)\cong S_3$